# Why don't I see the text from Google's excerpt when I visit a site?

Tags: google-search

Sometimes, after opening a Google search result, I discover that the text from the excerpt is nowhere to be found on that page.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The list is hidden. Select `full list of downloads for your platform.` and you will see what you are looking for.

Comment: No need to close, just change the title into something less of a rant ;-)

Comment: @Ivo - unfortunately I don't have edit privileges yet.

Comment: Google only fibs they do not lie.

Comment: I can't see how this is closed as 'not a real question.'  It may be that it isn't a sophisticated question, or the OP doesn't seem like the web-app 'power-user' that we hope to attract, but is seems that the question has been ostensibly answerable.

Comment: @FarmBoy - I think part of the problem is the "rant" nature of the title. I'm going to vote to reopen in the hope that @raven (or somebody else with edit powers) changes it.

Comment: I made it into something less of a rant, so please reevaluate.

Comment: Based on the screenshot (with the number for Stack sites open) and the accounts linked, @raven knows how to ask a question and not a rant . On the first revision when I voted to close, it *seemed* (an assumption that could be wrong) as if it was a rant that did not have the backing of previous attempts to solve answer before consulting WA. Yes the question is answerable but I would hate for this to be the Yahoo Answers Alternative. There is a question and a thought out question. There is a reason why a preview of the question is given while you do your write up. It gives a chance to lookover.

Comment: In its new form , I have nominated it for a reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not lying.

The content could be from a cached version of the page. However, in this case if you view the source for that page you find the following:

```
<div style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;padding:5px 10px;width:420px;
 border:1px solid #bcbcbc;background:#FFFFAF;"><a name="windowsffport">
 LastPass Portable for Firefox</a></div>
```

There are actually 27 instances of the word "Portable" on the page. It's just that the text isn't visible on the default "Recommended" tab of that page. If you click on the "Windows" tab that text becomes visible.

Answer (score 2):

The description (which is sometimes out of date) is taken and stored in Google's cache and not directly from the site.  The page can very well change from the time the page is cached.  Also it's possible that the description is from a section of the page that is not visible (for example hidden div until some action is performed).

Why does Google display descriptions from cache instead of from the live site?

Imagine if every time someone searched, Google had to make a request to your page to get the actual live content.  This would mean much more traffic and a lot slower results.